# What is NUI_LOCKED_RECT and what does the Pitch represent? (kinect)

Tags: c++, kinect-sdk

The documentation says: Defines the surface for a locked rectangle.
I'm trying to understand this code.

What I understand so far:

Create an image frame;
Get the texture interface of the image frame:
(Represents an object containing image frame data that is similar to a Direct3D texture, but has only one level (does not support mipmapping).)

Lock the buffer for read and write access.

```
NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;
NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;

INuiFrameTexture* texture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
texture->LockRect(0,&LockedRect,NULL,0);

    if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0)
```

What I don't understand is the process of locking a buffer for a INUIFrameTexture and I also don't understand what the LockedRect.Pitch means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to lock the buffer because the kinect mustn't read/rewrite it, so move the buffer into a `NUI_LOCKED_RECT`. `LockedRect.Pitch` is the number of bytes of data in a row of your locked `rect`.